# Проблема с написанием калькулятора JS

Tags: javascript

Доброго времени суток!

Помогите разобраться, я только начал изучать front.
Делал калькулятор, вроде работает, но есть нюансы: не могу сделать что бы он считал вот так, например: 5 + 4 + 4+ 3 и тд. Он при нажатии на '=' добавляет только последнюю цифру.

сам код:

```
<script>
      let firstNum = '' // первое число
      let secondNum = '' // второе число
      let arithmetic = '' //  арифметика
      let stop = false

      let digits = ['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '.']
      let arithmeticGo = ['-', '+', '/', '*']

      let outScreen = document.querySelector('.calculator_screen p')

      function clearScreen() {
        // очистка

        firstNum = ''
        secondNum = ''
        arithmetic = ''
        stop = false
        outScreen.textContent = 0
      }

      // AC
      document.querySelector('.ac').onclick = clearScreen

      document.querySelector('.buttons').onclick = (event) => {
        if (!event.target.classList.contains('btn')) return

        if (event.target.classList.contains('ac')) return

        outScreen.textContent = ''

        // беру кнопку которую нажимаю
        var key = event.target.textContent

        // условие, если нажат арифметический знак
        if (digits.includes(key)) {
          if (secondNum == '' && arithmetic == '') {
            firstNum += key

            outScreen.textContent = firstNum
          } else if (firstNum !== '' && secondNum !== '' && stop) {
            secondNum = key
            stop = false
            outScreen.textContent = secondNum
          } else {
            secondNum += key
            outScreen.textContent = secondNum
          }
          // console.log(firstNum, secondNum, arithmetic)
          return
        }

        // если нажата кнопка / * - +
        if (arithmeticGo.includes(key)) {
          arithmetic = key
          if (key) {
            outScreen.textContent = firstNum
          }
          // outScreen.textContent = arithmetic // убираем знак
          // console.log(arithmetic) // проверяем
          return
        }

        if (key === '=') {
          if (secondNum === '') secondNum = firstNum

          switch (arithmetic) {
            case '+':
              firstNum = +firstNum + +secondNum // избегаем конкатенации
              break

            case '-':
              firstNum = firstNum - secondNum
              break

            case '*':
              firstNum = firstNum * secondNum
              break

            case '/':
              if (secondNum === '0') {
                outScreen.textContent = 'На ноль делить нельзя!'
                firstNum = ''
                secondNum = ''
                arithmetic = ''

                return
              }
              firstNum = firstNum / secondNum

              break

              
          }
          stop = true
          outScreen.textContent = firstNum
          // console.log(firstNum, secondNum, arithmetic)
        }
      }
    </script>
```

Comment: Ну правильно, у тебя же в коде так и написано, что считать арифметику только после нажатия на равно, а не каждый раз при нажатии на кнопку арифметики

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Если можно, то покажите примером

Comment: А что не ясно я написал? Почему это не можете вы сами написать? Я же ничего сложного не описал

Comment: Не сложно это для вас, а я только начал изучать и мне не совсем понятно, как описать условие: считать каждый раз при нажатии на кнопку арифметика.  Толи это в if() описать как то, или в событии. Научусь не буду задавать такие вопросы.